# Android device not getting recognized by adb manager in Ubuntu OS(Emulator is recognized)

Tags: android, ubuntu, flutter, adb

I am trying to work on flutter . Flutter doctor is not detecting my Android device.But it is detecting the Android emulator.

I am using brand new Redmi Note 7 with developer options on.

UBUNTU 18.04 OS

1) Tried with all three USB options 
Use USB for 
No Data transfer
File Transfer
Transfer Photos (PTP)

2) when I check with adb devices
The device is not getting detected

> adb devices

I am working on Flutter Flutter doctor is not recognising my android device. I am using brand new Redmi Note 7 for testing

krishvek@krishvek-Inspiron-N4030:~$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /home/krishvek/flutter_dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (7 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/krishvek/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/krishvek/Desktop/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/krishvek/Desktop/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at /home/krishvek/intellJ/idea-IC-191.6183.87
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 191.6183.88

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

krishvek@krishvek-Inspiron-N4030:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *

krishvek@krishvek-Inspiron-N4030:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/krishvek/flutter_dev/flutter/bin:/home/krishvek/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/krishvek/Android/sdk/platform-tools/:/home/krishvek/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/krishvek/Android/sdk/platform-tools/

It should recognize android device

Comment: Does the version of your Android SDK match the version of Android on your phone?

Comment: in Mi devices there is a thing called MIUI optimizations...try to turn it off.